# Stochastic operator on $\ell^1$ has dense range

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $P:\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}^d) \rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{Z}^d)$
be given by

$$(Pz)(x)=\sum_{y \tilde \ x} \frac{1}{2d} z(y)$$

where the tilde indicates that $y$ is a neighboured vertex of $x.$

I would like to know: Let $\lambda \notin [-1,1]$ is it true that 
$\operatorname{ran}(P-\lambda)$ is dense in $\ell^1.$ In other words, does this operator have no residual spetrum outside $[-1,1]?$

Background: If we look at $P$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ this operator is even self-adjoint and thus there is no residual spectrum at all.

Comment: you mean that each vertex has $2^d$ neighbours? It looks strange.

Comment: What for $d=3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true (if we replace $2^d$ to $2d$). If the range of $P-\lambda$ is not dense, there exists a bounded linear functional $\eta\in \ell^\infty=(\ell^1)^*$ which vanishes on this range. In other words, there exists a not identically zero bounded function $\eta$ on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ which satisfies $P^*\eta=P\eta=\lambda\eta$. Consider two cases.

1) $|\lambda|>1$. Note that since $\eta(x)=\lambda^{-1}(2d)^{-1}\sum_{y\sim x} \eta(y)$, the sum of coeffcients on the right is $\lambda^{-1}$. Iterating this, we see that each $\eta(x)$ is a linear combination of other values of $\eta$ with sum of coefficients $\lambda^{-n}$ for any $n$. Since $\lambda^{-n}$ tends to 0 and $\eta$ is bounded, we conclude that $\eta\equiv 0$, a contradiction.

2) $\lambda$ is not real. Denote $\mu=2d \lambda$. Take large $N$ and denote $\Omega_N=[-N,N]^d\cap \mathbb{Z}^d$. Consider the sum $S_n=\sum_{x\in \Omega_N,y\sim x} \eta(y)\overline{\eta(x)}$. It equals, if we replace $\sum_{y\sim x} \eta(y)$ to $\mu \eta(x)$, to $S_n=\mu\sum_{x\in \Omega_n}|\eta(x)|^2$. On the other hand, all internal edges have real contribution to this sum. For boundary edges use an estimate $2|\eta(y)\overline{\eta(x)}|\leqslant |\eta(x)|^2+|\eta(y)|^2$. Then denoting $\mu=u+iv$ and taking the imaginary part, we get $|v|\sum_{x\in \Omega_n} |\eta(x)|^2\leqslant 2\sum_{x\in \Omega_{n+1}\setminus \Omega_{n-1}} |\eta(x)|^2$. Now denote $a_n=\sum_{x\in \Omega_n} |\eta(x)|^2$. This sequence is positive for large $n$, increases and satisfies an inequality $a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}\geqslant ca_n$ for certain positive $c=|v|/2$. It follows by induction that $a_n\geqslant c_0 \rho^n$, where $\rho >1$ is a root of $\rho ^2-1=c\rho$. On the other hand, since $\eta$ is bounded, $a_n=O(n^d)$. A contradiction.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but sorry, where does this estimate after "Then denoting $\mu=u+iv$, we get" come from. Would you mind spending a few more words on this? Otherwise, I could completely follow your thoughts.

Comment: It looks to me that the Wiener algebra on the torus is as good as on the circle, so the operator is actually invertible. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @fedja could I please ask you to elaborate on this in an answer, this does sound very interesting to me. I did suspect invertibility as well, but wanted to look for an easier conjecture first.

Comment: @fedja or would you mind just briefly outlining invertibility as a comment below my question?

Comment: @BaoLing Just google Wiener's theorem/Wiener algebra and mimic the proof you like most :-)

Comment: @BaoLing I have taken imaginary part of $S_n$, it equals $v a_n$, on the other hand, it may appear only from the boundary edges, which may be estimated as $2\sum_{x\in \Omega_{n+1}\setminus \Omega_{n-1}} |\eta(x)|^2$. Maybe even multiple 2 is not necessary.

Comment: @fedja ah, of course! You are correct and it is invertible.

Comment: @fedja sorry for asking again. The Wiener theorem I find says that if $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ has absolutely convergent Fourier series and $f$ does not vanish anywhere, then $\frac{1}{f}$ does so as well. I agree that this sounds similar in spirit  because $\mathbb{Z}^d$ corresponds to functions on $[-\pi,\pi]^d$ by the Fourier transform, but I want to show invertibility of some operator. How is this related?

Comment: @BaoLing Your operator is a multiplication by a function $f=\frac1{2d}\sum_{i=1}^d (x_i+x_i^{-1})-\lambda$. For $\lambda\notin [-1,1]$ this function does not have zeroes on the torus $|x_1|=\dots=|x_n|=1$, thus $1/f\in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ and multiplication by $1/f$ defines a bounded operator, which is inverse to yours.

Comment: @BaoLing Moreover, you do not even need the full strength of the Wiener theorem because all functions you deal with are infinitely smooth (even real-analytic) and therefore their Fourier series converge like crazy.

Comment: @FedorPetrov thank you for your help. let me try to understand this: The multiplication operator you wrote down is the Fourier transform of my operator, so it reads $f(k):=\frac{1}{2d} \sum_{i=1}^{d} (e^{ik_i}+e^{-ik_i})- \lambda.$ However, you seem to obtain that $f \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z}^d),$ really? How do you interpret this as an $\ell^1$ sequence, if it is a multiplication operator?

Comment: @FedorPetrov sorry, do I make sense to you?

Comment: No, $f$ has finite support: it has non-zero values (corr. $-\lambda$ and $1/2d$) at points $0,\pm e_i$, $i=1,\dots,d$. This of course belongs to $\ell^1$. And the operator is a convolution with this function. On the level of Fourier transform, we consider the operator which multiples an absolutely converging Laurent series (a series in $x_i,1/x_i$) by a Laurent polynomial $\frac1{2d}\sum_{i=1}^d (x_i+x_i^{-1})-\lambda$.